# C++ Load text file, optimization

Tags: c++, file, optimization, load, csv

There is my source code loading text file and delimitting each line to single  items (words).

How to further optimize the code? Testing empty lines (and other constructions) are (in my opinion) a little bit inefficient....

```
typedef std::vector < std::string >  TLines;
typedef std::vector < std::vector < std::string > > TItems;

TItems TFloadFile ( const char * file_name )
{
    //Load projection from file
    unsigned int lines = 0;
    char buffer[BUFF];
    FILE * file;
    TItems file_words;
    TLines file_lines;


    file = fopen ( file_name, "r" );

    if ( file != NULL )
    {
            for ( ; fgets ( buffer, BUFF, file ); )
            {
                    //Remove empty lines
                    bool empty_line = true;
                    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < strlen ( buffer ); i++ )
                    {
                            if ( !isspace ( ( unsigned char ) buffer[i] ) )
                            {
                                    empty_line = false;
                                    break;
                            }
                    }

                    if ( !empty_line )
                    {
                            file_lines.push_back ( buffer );
                            lines++;
                    }
            }


            file_words.resize ( lines + 1 );
            for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < lines; i++ )
            {
                    char * word = strtok ( const_cast<char *> ( file_lines[i].c_str() ), " \t,;\r\n" );
                    for ( int j = 0; word; j++, word = strtok ( 0, " \t;\r\n" ) )
                    {
                            file_words[i].push_back ( word );
                    }
            }

            fclose ( file );
    }

    return file_words;
}
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com is a good forum for this sort of question.

Comment: @All: Thank you for your opinions, comments, remarks and code samples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before optimizing, can you explain how big the file is, how long the code currently takes to execute and why you think it isn't already IO bound (ie due to hard disk speed). How long do you think it should take? Some idea of the type of data in the file would be good too (such as average line length, average proportion of empty lines etc).

That said, combine the remove-empty-line loop with the word-tokenising loop. Then you can remove TLines altogether and avoid the std::string constructions and vector push-back. I haven't checked this code works, but it should be close enough to give you the idea. It also includes a more efficient empty line spotter:

```
if ( file != NULL )
{
    for ( ; fgets ( buffer, BUFF, file ); )
    {
        bool is_empty = true;
        for (char *c = buffer; *c != '\0'; c++)
        {
            if (!isspace(c))
            {
                is_empty = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (is_empty)
            continue;

        file_words.resize ( lines + 1 );
        char * word = strtok ( buffer, " \t,;\r\n" );
        for ( int j = 0; word; j++, word = strtok ( 0, " \t;\r\n" ) )
        {
                file_words[i].push_back ( word );
        }

        lines++;
    }

    fclose ( file );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The line `for ( unsigned i = 0; i < strlen ( buffer ); i++ )` is quite inefficient as you're calculating the length of `buffer` each time through the loop. However, it's possible that this will be optimised away by the compiler.

You're pushing items onto your `std::vector`s without `reserve()`ing any space. For large file, this will involve a lot of overhead as the content of the vectors will need to be copied in order to resize them. I just read @Notinlist's answer, which already talks about the inefficiencies of `std::vector::resize()`.

Instead of reading each line into a vector through repeated `fgets()` calls, could you not simply determine the number of bytes in the file, dynamically allocate a `char` array to hold them, and then dump the bytes into it? Then, you could parse the words and store them in `file_words`. This would be more efficient than the method you're currently using.

Comment: "However, it's possible that this will be optimized away by the compiler." The compiler would have to know that this function as no side-effects, so in general this isn't true (unless the compiler does link-time analysis)

Comment: @Kamchatka: Fair enough, thanks. All the more reason to store this value in a variable and reference that instead of recalculating it for each pass.

Answer (score 0):

For one

```
file_lines.push_back ( buffer );
```

That is a **very** expensive line. If you don't have to use vector, then use a list instead. Maybe convert your list to a vector after you finished with the job.

If you absolutely in need of using vector for this purpose, then you should use some exponential increment instead, like:

```
if(file_lines.size()<=lines){
    file_lines.resize((int)(lines * 1.3 + 1));
}
```

That way you will have much less cpu intensive .resize() operations, for a cost of minimal memory consumption overhead.

Comment: Why resize at all - let vector do that for itself - it will use exponential increments.

Comment: You may use .reserve() instead of .resize().

Comment: @Mark: Did not know about that. Reference?

Comment: @Notinlist: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/reserve/. `std::vector::reserve` is your friend :)
Edit: Whoops, I misread; I thought you hadn't heard of `reserve` haha. My bad.

Comment: @Notinlist - can't find a reference but found in code and patching an accepted error in an old VC++ library

Comment: @Notinlist, Mark: I took a quick look through the C++03 standard and I couldn't find a mention of exponential increments; I think it may be implementation-specific. That said, I was looking in the `vector` part of the standard, when perhaps I should have been looking at `allocator`. Regardless, exponential increments would probably be the most sensible option.

Comment: The exponential growth is an implicit requirement of the standard. It is the only way to get amortized constant time insertion. Check the value returned by `vector::capacity` to see the behavior of your implementation.

Comment: @pmr: Good point, you wouldn't have constant amortised time insertion for anything less than exponential growth; Once you reached a large enough number of elements the resize overhead would be too inefficient . Something concrete from the spec would still be nice though.

Comment: @ChrisParton Look at the complexity of `vector::push_back` it says 'amortized constant time'. What more do you need? What is more important is, that the factor of growth is implementation dependent.

Comment: @pmr: I was agreeing with you.

Comment: For example a factor of 845 would be unpleasant. Maybe a factor of 2 is overkill for some (which seems to be the case for many implementations). I would choose something like 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified and converted to use `std::list` instead of `std::vector`.

```
typedef std::list< std::list< std::string > > TItems;

TItems TFloadFile ( const char * file_name )
{
    using namespace std;
    //Load projection from file
    ifstream file(file_name);
    TItems file_words;
    string line;

    for(getline(file,line); !file.fail() && !file.eof(); getline(file,line))
    {
        file_words.push_back(list<string>());
        list<string> &words(file_words.back());

        char *word = strtok((char*)line.c_str(), " \t,;\r\n" );
        for(; word; word=strtok( 0, " \t;\r\n" ))
        {
            words.push_back( word );
        }
        if(!words.size())
            file_words.pop_back();
    }
    return file_words;
}
```